# Persistant table in test database for Rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, cucumber

I have a couple of tables: `cities` and `provinces` that I have filled from a sql file directly to the database in both development and test, without using migrations or a seed file in Ruby. Straight SQL.

Everytime the test runs with Selenium the database gets erased, and therefore I need to run the `mysql (...) database_test < fill_cities_provinces.sql`

How can I fix this? Can I make two tables not erasable in test?

I notice it just happens if the scenario is marked with `@javascript`. Otherwise, if it uses the default driver, that content of that table doesn't get erased.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [DatabaseCleaner](http://rdoc.info/gems/database_cleaner) to clean up the database during tests. The following strategy should help

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[cities provinces]}
```